# Why does arsenic form four 2-electron bonds in a germanium lattice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics

The [Feynman Lectures on Physics volume III, section 14-2](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_14.html) says this (emphasis mine):

> Suppose we imagine a crystal of germanium in which one of the germanium atoms is replaced by an arsenic atom. The germanium atoms have a valence of 4 and the crystal structure is controlled by the four valence electrons. Arsenic, on the other hand, has a valence of 5. It turns out that a single arsenic atom can sit in the germanium lattice (because it has approximately the correct size), but **in doing so it must act as a valence 4 atom**—using four of its valence electrons to form the crystal bonds and having one electron left over.

So arsenic forms four bonds, giving it a valency of 9, and filling the outer shells of the neighbouring germaniums. I can imagine the following alternative options, though:

- Arsenic forms three bonds, giving it a valency of 8, and leaving one of the outer shells of the neighbouring germaniums with a valency of 7, whilst filling the other three outer shells
- Arsenic forms three 2-electron bonds and one 1-electron bond, filling it and its neighbours' outer shells

Why aren't these as preferable? Wouldn't arsenic "prefer" to have eight electrons in its outer shell?

Comment: Arsenic uses 4 electrons to form 4 bonds, giving it a valency of 4 and one electron left over which is not involved in bonding. It doesn't have enough electrons to fill the outer shell. It cannot attract more from the lattice around it. This would be so much negative charge that Coulomb repulsion would prevent it.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35579/why-does-phosphorus-give-a-free-electron-in-silicon-doping/35588#35588